# How to pass data from Fragment to DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

I have a `Fragment` with 2 `ArrayList`s containing `Strings` that I would like to pass from the `Fragment` to show some information in a `DialogFragment`. However, I'm currently lost as to what code I should be using to achieve this objective. I tried adding `private val myListTitles: ArrayList<String>, private val myListDescriptions: ArrayList<String>` to the constructor of the fragment class, but that didn't work. What's the correct way to implement a `for` loop and get the position of each item rather than hardcoding each item 1-by-1?

**Fragment class**

```
class MyFragment : androidx.fragment.app.Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val myListTitles = ArrayList<String>()
        myListTitles.add("Tab A")
        myListTitles.add("Tab B")
        myListTitles.add("Tab C")

        val myListDescriptions = ArrayList<String>()
        myListDescriptions.add("Description A")
        myListDescriptions.add("Description B")
        myListDescriptions.add("Description C")


        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

**DialogFragment class**

```
class TabbedDialog : DialogFragment(private val myListTitles: ArrayList<String>, private val myListDescriptions: ArrayList<String>) {
    lateinit var customView: View

    private var myListTitles = myList.toMutableList()
    private var myListDescriptions = myList.toMutableList()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return customView
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val b = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setTitle("Dialog Title")
                .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

        customView = activity!!.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)

        val tabLayout = customView.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.mTabLayout)
        val viewPager = customView.findViewById<ViewPager>(R.id.mViewPager)

        val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment("Tab A", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description A"))
        adapter.addFragment("Tab B", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description B"))
        adapter.addFragment("Tab C", TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance("Description C"))

        val adapter = TabbedDialogAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        for (item in myList) {
            // ¿What goes here?

            // My guess
            // adapter.addFragment(myListTitles[position], TabbedDialogFragment.createInstance(myListDescriptions[position]))
        }

        viewPager.adapter = adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

        b.setView(customView)
        return b.create()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to pass data from one fragment to another is to create a static factory method and then pass the arguments via the fragment `arguments` bundle, like this:

```
class MyDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var items: List<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        items = arguments?.getStringArrayList(ITEMS) ?: throw IllegalStateException("No args provided")
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        /* omitted */
    }

    companion object {

        private const val ITEMS = "items"

        fun newInstance(
                items: ArrayList<String>
        ): MyDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putStringArrayList(ITEMS, items)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Edit:

in your fragment you would call it like this

```
val dialog = MyDialogFragment.newInstance(items)
dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog")
```

Comment: What about in the 'MyFragment' `Fragment`? Does any code in there need to change?

Comment: Function "`newInstance`" is never used.

Comment: You would use the newInstance function to instantiate the dialog fragment, instead of calling the default constructor.

Comment: Using that code in my fragment resturns this error: `Unresolved reference: items`

Comment: You most likely need to pass *two* lists, because that's how *your* code is. The answer provided is just an illustration of how you'd pass *one* list of strings.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I want to use the list of strings in my `Fragment` rather than creating a list in my `RecyclerView` adapter. Also, what do I need to create with `items` in the Fragment? A list? I don't understand that part.

Comment: I assume it's meant to represent how you're supposed to send over `myListTitles` and `myListDescriptions` as part of the arguments bundle so that it would work reliably in your DialogFragment. So in your case, `items` is `myListTitles`. And you'd also add `myListDescriptions`.